ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mysite' when I am running "py manage.py runserver"
(dev) D:\DEV\audit_management>py manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute
super().execute(*args, **options)
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 81, in handle
if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
    
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
               
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      
File "C:\Users\berhe.kalayu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line   
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mysite'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\DEV\audit_management\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "D:\DEV\audit_management\manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in  
utility.execute()
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in run_from_argv
connections.close_all()
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 84, in close_all
for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
        
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 76, in all
return 
       
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
return iter(self.settings)
           
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 47, in __get_ res =    

instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)                                   
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
                
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
            
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
           
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                
File "D:\DEV\dev\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
     
File "C:\Users\berhe.kalayu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line   
90, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mysite'

I try uninstall both python(3.12.4) and django(5.0.7),install them again, install django globally in   
and venv, create my projects in different directories but it doesn't work.

